# Error en piedra papel o tijera en PHP

Tags: php, variables

les quiero pedir ayuda para mi problema, estoy haciendo un juego con php de piedra papel o tijera y en la parte en la que cuenta las veces que has perdido, ganado y empatado el contador no aumenta y creo que es porque la variable vale 0 cada vez que recarga la pagina la recarga a su valor original. la variable como la que les voy a enseñar asi son todas solo que con diferentes nombre, em es de empate y def de derrotas.

```
<?php

$wins = 0; 

?>
```

Y el siguiente pedazo de codigo es de la pagina principal en la que se supone que tendria que mostrar el aumento de los contadores.

```
include 'Contador/wins.php';
include 'Contador/derrotas.php';
include'Contador/empates.php';
    
    echo "Haz ganado un total de: $wins  veces".'<br>';
    echo "Haz perdido un total de: $def veces".'<br>';
    echo "Haz empatado un total de: $em veces".'<br>';
```

Espero haberme explicado bien y que me ayuden con mi problema.Gracias.

Comment: Independientemente de que definas las variables, no estás guardando los valores, ya sea en sesiones, cookies, base de datos, etc. Podrías comenzar con sesiones; en el manual de PHP hay un ejemplo de [uso básico](https://www.php.net/manual/es/session.examples.basic.php)

Comment: ¿Estás guardando la información? Ya que solo veo declarada las variables, más no sé si las almacenas en un algún lado, de no ser así, verifica primero este punto.

Comment: Si es algo muy simple y no quieres complicarte con base de datos, puedes crear un archivo json y actualizar la información de las partidas en él.

Answer (score 1):

Debes almacenar el valor que quieres mantener a lo largo del tiempo en algún lugar que persista el dato. Esto puedes realizarlo de múltiples formas y métodos como por ejemplo utilizar una base de datos, guardarlo en un archivo, utilizar una cookie o utilizar las variables de sessión por ejemplo.

Un ejemplo sencillo de sesiones con php podría ser el siguiente

```
<?php
// Inicializamos la session, esto hace que las variables de session esten disponibles
// Se debe declarar antes de imprimir cualquier dato
session_start();
// Comprovamos si la variable de session existe y no es null
// si existe utilizamos el valor que contenga, en caso contrario la inicializamos con un valor 0
$_SESSION['win'] = $_SESSION['win'] ?? 0;

// Incrementamos el valor de la variable para ver que cambia a lo largo del tiempo
// aqui almacenarias el valor a persistir
$_SESSION['win']++;

// mostramos por pantalla
echo $_SESSION['win'];
```

Puedes obtener mas información en la documentación de php:

- [$_SESSION](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.session.php)
- [session_start()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.session-start.php)

Comment: Gracias ya me funciono :)